# Getting exception while set data in edittext coming from JSON parsing in Android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am Getting response and parsed data and store in String now  i to show in Edittext i am getting following exceptions .i am getting Response and parsing in AsyncTask

```
    05-02 10:13:56.797: W/System.err(17935): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2812)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:607)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:633)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2505)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5115)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:3661)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:6352)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:6477)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:906)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:611)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:514)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:74)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:85)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:497)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2712)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:149)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
    05-02 10:13:56.867: W/System.err(17935):    at com.smartbuzz.contax.Profil.getServerResponse(Profil.java:262)
    05-02 10:13:56.877: W/System.err(17935):    at com.smartbuzz.contax.Profil$Testing.doInBackground(Profil.java:357)
    05-02 10:13:56.877: W/System.err(17935):    at com.smartbuzz.contax.Profil$Testing.doInBackground(Profil.java:1)
    05-02 10:13:56.877: W/System.err(17935):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    05-02 10:13:56.877: W/System.err(17935):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    05-02 10:13:56.877: W/System.err(17935):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    05-02 10:13:56.877: W/System.err(17935):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    05-02 10:13:56.877: W/System.err(17935):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
```

Comment: post some code snippet

Comment: as in Log `CalledFromWrongThreadException` clearly means you are trying to update UI elements from `doInBackground` method of AsyncTask. so use `onPostExecute` for updating UI elements when doInBackground  execution complete

Comment: i.e. You are trying to update UI from a worker thread.

Comment: add runonUiThread for set text in edittext...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the `setText()` method of your `EditText` from a worker thread. All the UI elements can only be updated from the main thread.

In your `AsyncTask` , the `setText()` method should be called in `onPostExecute()` instead in `doInBackground()`